# Echoing piped output

Tags: bash

Is there a way to echo output that being piped to the next command? For example lets say that I can reading filenames from a text file and then running a command on that file:

```
cat files.txt | xargs -I{} -d"\n" command
```

The command runs and the output is displayed in the terminal, is there a way to print out the filename as well?

Lets say the input file contains:

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
```

Intended output:

```
file1.txt
[output of command with file1.txt as input]
file2.txt
[output of command with file2.txt as input]
```

Is there a way to get `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` in stdout as well?

Answer (score 0):

You better write function :

```
Function()
{
cat file1.txt | xargs -I{} -d"\n" command >> /dev/console;
cat file2.txt | xargs -I{} -d"\n" command >>/dev/console;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `cat` is more work as you have a subprocess. Using a while loop would be faster I guess

```
while read filename
do
# do something with $filename
done<file_to_be_processed
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the filename you want to use `echo`  to get the content you can use `cat`. If you want to stay flexible (and e.g. exchange your `cat files.txt` with a `find ....` command you should stay with your invocation of `xargs` but only do it a file at the time:

```
 cat files.txt | xargs -L 1 /path/to/your_script
```

with `your_script`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1
cat $1
```

Answer (score 0):

Shell command `tee` does exactly what you are asking for (echoes output that is being piped to the next command). Just pipe it to `tee` (`some_command | tee`). Lookup man pages for the command to get exact usage, examples and any other details.